# Avoid UI freeze during a computationally heavy call

Tags: javascript

I have the following event listener

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 this.classList.add('disabled');
 aFunctionThatTakesLongToExecute();
});
```

The problem is that the repaint on the screen associated with the newly added class for the button takes place on when the execution of **aFunctionThatTakesLongToExecute** is completed and that creates a stutter-y user experience.

Is there a way to force a repaint even while the javascript function is executing?

Comment: Move the function to a web worker. That's what they're there for.

Comment: I don't really understand the behavior you're describing, but you can wrap your function call like this : `setTimeout(aFunctionThatTakesLongToExecute);`. Basically, it calls your method asynchronously immediatly. (wrote more details in the answer)

Comment: aFunctionThatTakesLongToExecute it doesn't take any param ?

Comment: No, it does not take any params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the behavior you're describing, but you can wrap your function call like this :

```
setTimeout(aFunctionThatTakesLongToExecute);
```

Basically, it calls your method asynchronously and immediatly, as `setTimeout` second parameter is not set (usually it is the time before execution in milliseconds).

Keep in mind that this syntax works if `aFunctionThatTakesLongToExecute` does not take any parameters. Else, you have to wrap the function call in another (anonymous) function and give that new function to the setTimeout instruction like this :

```
setTimeout(() => {
    aFunctionThatTakesLongToExecute(yourParameter);
});
```

Here's a link to the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Thanks, I was just hoping that there is something else.

Comment: There is no reason to use something else. You have an function with a high time cost. Just make it run "in the background", that's the point of asynchronous functions calls.